# Prevent single attribute from firing this.bind("change")

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

In Backbone.js, I have a model I am binding a change event to, but I want to prevent this from happening on specific attribute changes.  For example, I want it to fire for every single time `model.set()` is called, *except* when calling `model.set({arbitraryName: value})`.

Here's what I have:

```
this.bind("change", function() {
  this.update();
});
```

But I have no clue how to determine what is being set--any ideas?

**EDIT**

It looks like I can call

```
model.set({arbitraryName: value}, {silent: true})
```

to prevent the change event from firing (which works for what I need), but what if I have something bound like:

```
this.bind("change:arbitraryName", functionName)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider using `hasChanged` in the event handler?

```
var self = this;
this.bind("change", function() {
    if(!self.hasChanged("someAttribute")){
        self.update();
    }
});
```

I'm not sure I understand your question completely.  Please notice the difference of the above, and the below.

```
this.bind("change:someAttribute", function(){
    self.update();
});
```

The first one will fire `update` on any change where `someAttribute` remains constant.  The second one will fire update on any change to `someAttribute`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now how did I miss that?  Thanks!